# Most open and standards-compliant format for a JSON news feed

Tags: json, web, rss, feed, atom-feed

I can find a huge amount of converters for Atom or RSS to JSON. I can see App.Net and a Google Feed API for pushing feeds in JSON which seem to have traction. What I am struggling to figure out is what's the 'open standard' way of serving up a feed without tying people to transform XML or to use my own (or someone else's) proprietary JSON format.

Comment: anyone got any suggestions about what tags i could add to this to get an opine?

Answer (score 0):

At this point, I don't think there is anything like this. By definition JSON is schema-less, which means that you'll have a hard time finding the RSS or Atom of JSON.

Comment: So because json has no schema no-one is publishing a standard definition of what a feed is? And that's the definition of json? So when google describe their json feed format is that something outside of json? And that cannot happen to anyone describing a feed in a standard format? Or are you saying only corporations can use json as it has no standard formats? Or is it the case that no-one cares about standards?

Comment: Mostly, it is that nobody really wants to agree with someone else on a schema. Google says: "let's use mine", Facebook says "Nah, let's use mine", Twitter says "Nah, mine is better", Apple says "You don't get it, mine is the one we should all use"... etc. Typical prisoner's dillema!

Comment: Its a shame that there isn't an RFC. I am wanting to create a json feed and am having to consider the merits of using google or app.net formats or some other I may not know about. I am not sure of the legal soundness of copying their formats. Nor the future likelihood that folks will write parsers and viewers for any given format.